# Repeated use of parameter for multiple UDF's in FROM throws an invalid column name error

Tags: t-sql, ssms, user-defined-functions

When using multiple table-valued functions in a query like beneath, SSMS throws an error. Also, the [Date] parameter of [PRECALCPAGES_asof] is underlined in red.

I am trying to understand why this fails. I think this might be related to the way the SQL Server engine works. Have looked into documentation on MSDN but unfortunately I do not know what to look for. Why is this caused and is there a way around it?

**Query**

```
SELECT
    [Date]
    , COUNT(*)
FROM
    [Warehouse].[dbo].[DimDate]
    CROSS APPLY 
    [PROJECTS_asof]([Date])
    INNER JOIN
    [PRECALCPAGES_asof]([Date]) ON [PRECALCPAGES_asof].[PROJECTID] = [PROJECTS_asof].[PROJECTID]
GROUP BY
    [Date]
```

**Error**

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'Date'.
```

**Functions**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [ProfitManager].[PROJECTS_asof]
(
    @date DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT
        [PROJECTID]
        , [PROJECT]
        , ...
    FROM
        Profitmanager.[PROJECTS_HISTORY]
    WHERE
        [RowStartDate] <= @date
        AND
        [RowEndDate] > @date
)
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [ProfitManager].[PRECALCPAGES_asof]
(
    @date DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT
        [PAGEID]
        , [PAGENAME]
        , ...
    FROM
        Profitmanager.[PRECALCPAGES_HISTORY]
    WHERE
        [RowStartDate] <= @date
        AND
        [RowEndDate] > @date
)
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't use fields from tables as parameters to a function in a join. You should use cross apply.

```
SELECT
    [Date]
    , COUNT(*)
FROM
    [Warehouse].[dbo].[DimDate]
    CROSS APPLY 
    [PROJECTS_asof]([Date])
    CROSS APPLY
    [PRECALCPAGES_asof]([Date])
WHERE
    [PRECALCPAGES_asof].[PROJECTID] = [PROJECTS_asof].[PROJECTID]
GROUP BY
    [Date]
```

Comment: It has to do with the statement evaulation order I think.

Comment: Looked up statement evaluation order. It looks like JOIN's are executed before APPLY's. Meaning [Date] would not be available by the time the JOIN is executed. Makes sense. Thanks again.